# String size limitation in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to automate a boring stuff with Python. It's almost done but I have a problem with strings in a list.

I collect some data line by line from a .txt file, I put it in a list and I change some strings that need to be changed.

The problem is that the length of the string in my list seems to be limited by the length of the previous one (the string from the text in my case).

To resume for example if `len(data[0]) = 5`. If I'm trying to put a string with 6 characters or more it will be cut.

How can I deal with that? An idea?

Thanks.

EDITED :

```
def dxf_copy_lines(f):
    text = f.readlines()
    i = 0
    lines_copied = []
    lines_to_delete = set(())
    while text[i] != 'TEXT\n':
        i = i + 1
    j = i
    while text[j] != 'VIEWPORT\n':
        lines_copied = np.append(lines_copied, text[j])
        j = j + 1
    print(lines_copied)
    return lines_copied

def modify_lines(lines_copied, ref_dim, id_f,num):

    n = len(lines_copied)
    for i in range(n):
        print (lines_copied[i][0:5])
        if lines_copied[i][0:5] == 'nazwa':
            lines_copied[i] = ref_dim.rstrip() + ' Pos. '+ id_f.rstrip()
        if lines_copied[i][0:3] == 'szt':
            lines_copied[i] = 'szt: ' + num +'\n'
    print(lines_copied)
    return lines_copied
```

Comment: You're going to need to post your code if you want help figuring out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Can you post ur code here?

Comment: Post the code, it's essential here.

Comment: This is not a property of Python lists, and would be something else in your code that would have to cause this. You need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is in this line : lines_copied[i] = ref_dim.rstrip() + ' Pos. '+ id_f.rstrip()

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Copy your code directly from your text editor, and paste it in question. Then highlight it and press Ctrl-K

Comment: It's done. Sorry..

Comment: Why in the world are you using `numpy.append`???

Comment: what are the typical values of `ref_dim` and `id_f`?

Comment: Is it a bad idea? It was the simpliest because I don't know the lenght of my list in advance..

Comment: They are strings. Example : '10x52x180'

Comment: *Why are you using `numpy` at all*, and not just a `list`??? What Python version are you on?

Comment: Python 3.6.1. I used numpy because it was the simplest way for me. Is there an other way?

Comment: Yes. Use a *Python list*

Comment: Ok. Dit it. It's working. I don't know why I always use Numpy. Bad habits. Thank you.

Comment: @LoïcKreseski I added an explanation below of the behavior you are seeing. Fundamentally, the problem is that you *aren't using a list, you are using a numpy array* which fixes the size of it's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `numpy` arrays. And this is certainly *not* a use-case for `numpy` arrays. Consider:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lines = []
>>> text = ['abc','de','fghk','lmnop','qrs']
>>> for line in text:
...     lines = np.append(lines, line)
...
>>> lines
array(['abc', 'de', 'fghk', 'lmnop', 'qrs'],
      dtype='<U32')
```

So `lines` is a `numpy.ndarray` of `dtype='<U32'`. Arrays elements are suppose to be *fixed size*. This is what allows `numpy` to do fast, numerical calculations. So, `dtype='<U32'` means that your array is of unicode-strings sized at 32. Consider what happens if I try to change an element of my array with a string that is bigger than 32:

```
>>> lines[2] = "this is an extremely, very very very, long long long, line"
>>> lines
array(['abc', 'de', 'this is an extremely, very very ', 'lmnop', 'qrs'],
      dtype='<U32')
```

It was truncated!

```
>>> len('this is an extremely, very very ')
32
```

Hopefully this makes sense now.

This is really not a use-case for `numpy`, it will actually be *slower* here. The following operation:

```
lines_copied = np.append(lines_copied, text[j])
```

Is O(N). Since you are doing it in a loop, it scales quadratically. A python list on the other hand, you could use `my_list.append(a_string)` and it will be a constant time operation!